# Android overriding PointF to get something close to java Point2D.double

Tags: java, android, graphics, point

I have a java method that returns `Point2D.double` and Android's closest class to this is `PointF`. The issue is that `PointF` returns **float** rather than **double**. Is there a way to override `PointF` so that it is double rather than float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you just convert your doubles to floats then use PointF, you could do that with a simple cast, unless you need to keep the data as doubles for some other purpose, if thats the case you could try extending the PointF class as below, it will be slower than just using PointF due to all the casting and manipulating of the doubles to floats etc but so long as your not calling it too often it should be ok!

```
public class pointD extends PointF{

public double x;
public double y;

public pointD(double x, double y){
    this.set((float) x,(float) y);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public double Length(){
    double l = (double)this.length();
    return l;
}

public final void set(double x, double y){
    this.set((float) x,(float) y);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
}
```

Comment: Is it better practice to do what you've done rather than writing a new class called PointD? (meaning copying the PointF class but making it deal solely with doubles). Would this be quicker than casting the floats to doubles?

Comment: It would be better to write your own class that only dealt with doubles, i'm not sure exactly what the overhead costs are in java for casting doubles to floats, but generally speaking it is best to avoid casts if possible. Also remember that a float uses 32bits for storage compared to 64bits for a double so perhaps it would be better to change your method to return a float rather than a double unless you need the extra precision that a double provides.

Comment: The reason I'm wanting to use doubles is because much of the math classes that I use return doubles rather than floats. I'm aiming to be consistent so I don't have to change many more methods that rely on doubles :) - Thank you for the response and help Kenny! (I went ahead with writing a PointD class